I can't import module OpenCV from Android Studio
I want to get a solution.
the error is this 
The error is 'specify location of the Gradle or android eslipse project'.
Please gave me the solution.
This is my path C:\Users\TAS-GOKUL KRISHNA\Downloads\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\java
But I didn't get the module. What the reason? And gave me solution.

This question is similar to: Cant import OpenCV module in android studio. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Looks like a duplicate question as the accepted answer in "Cant import OpenCV module in android studio" can be applicable. Could you please look into those steps?

just vote to close the question as a duplicate of this question you found, or if you don't have this privilege yet, then flag it as a duplicate
